# Comment out appSettings on web.config using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, web-config

I would like to know if someone can perform **commenting out this section on appSettings using PowerShell**. Sample code below: (just an example, not really my code)

```
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="TestDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/TestProject.csdl|res://*/TestProject.ssdl|res://*/TestProject.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SQL01;initial catalog=TestDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
   </connectionStrings>
   <appSettings>
      <add key="SCVMMServerName" value="VMM01" />
      <add key="SCVMMServerPort" value="8100" />
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I want to comment out this section:

```
<add key="SCVMMServerName" value="VMM01" />
```

resulting like this:

```
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="TestDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/TestProject.csdl|res://*/TestProject.ssdl|res://*/TestProject.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SQL01;initial catalog=TestDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
   </connectionStrings>
   <appSettings>
      <!--<add key="SCVMMServerName" value="VMM01" />-->
      <add key="SCVMMServerPort" value="8100" />
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Hope you guys *(especially PowerShell nerds out there)* can help me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$XmlDocument = [xml](Get-Content -Path "U:\test.xml")
$node = $XmlDocument.SelectNodes('//SomeNode') | Where-Object{$_.Key -eq "test2"}
$node.ParentNode.InnerXml = $node.ParentNode.InnerXml.Replace($node.OuterXml, $node.OuterXml.Insert(0, "<!--").Insert($node.OuterXml.Length+4, "-->"))
$XmlDocument.Save("U:\test.xml")
```

Comment: The third line is what I am looking for. Thanks for your help. I made it work on my code.

Comment: Greate to hear. Please mark it as answer when it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy to do in V3 and above.

```
(Get-Content c:\test.txt).replace('[Add value here]', 'New value') | Set-Content c:\test.txt
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This can only edit the value in the add key section. Like for example, in `<add key="SCVMMServerName" value="VMM01" />` , when this code is used, it will only modify "VMM01" to other value. What I want to do is to comment out the entire add key section.

Comment: Nope, it works fine for me.
(Get-Content C:\Users\RD\Desktop\test.config).replace('<add key="SCVMMServerName" value="VMM01" />', '<!--<add key="SCVMMServerName" value="VMM01" />-->') | Set-Content C:\Users\RD\Desktop\test.config